# Data Conversion Error After Add In "WHERE" clause and for Specific Data In Filter in SQL

Tags: sql-server, data-conversion

Currently I am experiencing one data conversation error as this

```
"Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint."
```

I know this error is due to the incompatible of data type. However it only happened if my WHERE clause (filter criteria) is solely that particular user and not for others so far. I wonder what gone wrong. I try to use CAST and CONVERT the bigint to nvarchar but it doesn't help.

The incompatible data types are between "survey_result.SR_ANSWER" as NVARCHAR and "survey_answer.SA_ID" as BIGINT in the first join. I will attach the code, the successful result (another end user data) and the error here.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT  
        survey_result.SR_SRHRESULTID,
        survey_header.SH_CODE AS SURVEY_CODE,
        survey_header.SH_DESCRIPTION AS SURVEY_NAME,
        survey_result_header.SRH_DATE SURVEY_DATE,
        survey_result.SR_DISTRIBUTOR AS DISTRIBUTOR_CODE,
        dist.DI_NAME DISTRIBUTOR_NAME,
        survey_result_header.SRH_RESPONDENT AS OUTLET_CODE,
        ol.OL_NAME AS OUTLET_NAME,
        survey_result.SR_SURVEYOR AS SALESPERSON_CODE,
        ui.UI_GIVENNAME AS SALESPERSON_NAME,
        survey_question.SQ_INDEX AS QUESTION_NO,
        survey_question.SQ_DESCRIPTION AS QUESTION,
        survey_answer.SA_DESCRIPTION AS RESULT
FROM SURVEYRESULT survey_result LEFT JOIN SURVEYANSWER survey_answer 
on survey_result.SR_SQID =survey_answer.SA_SQID AND survey_result.SR_ANSWER = survey_answer.SA_ID
JOIN SURVEYQUESTION survey_question on survey_question.SQ_ID = survey_result.SR_SQID
JOIN SURVEYHEADER survey_header on survey_question.SQ_SHID = survey_header.SH_ID
JOIN SURVEYRESULTHEADER survey_result_header on survey_result_header.SRH_SHID = survey_result.SR_SHID
AND survey_result_header.SRH_RESULTID = survey_result.SR_SRHRESULTID
AND survey_result_header.SRH_DISTRIBUTOR = survey_result.SR_DISTRIBUTOR
JOIN DISTRIBUTOR dist on dist.DI_DISTRICODE = survey_result.SR_DISTRIBUTOR
JOIN OUTLET ol on ol.OL_OUTLETCODE = survey_result_header.SRH_RESPONDENT
AND ol.OL_DISTRICODE = survey_result.SR_DISTRIBUTOR
JOIN USERINFO ui on ui.UI_USERNAME = survey_result.SR_SURVEYOR
WHERE survey_result_header.SRH_DATE >='2015-10-01' AND survey_result_header.SRH_DATE <='2015-10-31'
AND survey_question.SQ_TYPE IN('1','2','8')
AND survey_header.SH_CODE IN ('MONTALL','TONTALL')
AND survey_result.SR_SURVEYOR ='E08-128' /*this line cause error*/
```

Comment: You are saying for 'E08-128' the error is coming and not for other values for the survey_result.SR_SURVEYOR, am I correct? Basically you cant compare between `NVARCHAR` and `BIGINT` anyways just to try what are the values for  survey_result.SR_ANSWER and survey_answer.SA_ID when you select this user.

Comment: What data type is SR_SURVEYOR? Do you have any other fields with mismatched data types? In your posted query you are **not** _explicitly casting_ the problem fields that you mentioned. Try changing this : `survey_result.SR_ANSWER = survey_answer.SA_ID` to this: `survey_result.SR_ANSWER = CAST(survey_answer.SA_ID AS VARCHAR(30))` ad see if the error goes away.

Comment: @Abhishek, yes you are correct. I did select survey_result.SR_ANSWER and survey_answer.SA_ID in my select statement. Normally no error but when select this survey_result.SR_SURVEYOR it is impossible to get the result at all so I can't compare the result.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, wow you are my savior!!! It works like magic!! previously I CAST at the first level at the SELECT statement and it wont work at all! Thanks!!!

Comment: I have posted a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this :

```
survey_result.SR_ANSWER = survey_answer.SA_ID
```

to this

```
survey_result.SR_ANSWER = CAST(survey_answer.SA_ID AS VARCHAR(30))
```

and see if the error goes away.

If it does go away you should:

1. Find the data that is causing the issue (a non numeric value in the field `survey_answer.SA_ID`). You can use `SELECT * FROM survey_answer WHERE ISNUMERIC(SA_ID) = 0` to find it
2. Understand what impact this will have on your queries (i.e. this will never match to data in `survey_result.SR_ANSWER`)

Longer term you need to address your table design issue by:

1. Updating the data in survey_answer.SA_ID so it *is* numeric
2. Change the field to be numeric data type (not nvarchar)
3. Alter whatever application inserts data so that you can't insert non numeric data

Comment: I run the SELECT statement as per suggested but no results return. The data collected actually is from the radio button which have a fixed answer. Additionally, the survey_answer.SA_ID will indicate a integer number to survey_result table to get the real answer (as in nvarchar). thanks for your recommendation though and I greatly appreciated it. As for the long term solution, I am not the one who can decide on doing this because it is depends on the vendor of our company. Will suggest them the same way. Thanks.

Comment: Yes thats what I mentioned above: _this will never match data_. You need to look at the data in your table and work out why it doesn't match. i.e. it might be trying to match `'1'` to `'01'` - these don't match

Comment: Nick.McDermaid, thanks for the information as I am new to this sql. just saw your profile said you are incredibly handsome well that I can't judge, but you are incredibly smart. Thanks again.

Comment: haha well I think so. But seriously it really helps to understand your data - select from one table and use `WHERE` caluses to check out the data and indenttify particular rows that might cause you trouble. You really need to fix this issue in your database design as early as possible